# Prevent Firefox From Crashing When Being Terminated via Command Line TaskKill?

Tags: java, shell, firefox, command-line, terminal

I noticed that when I close FF in Java using through PID using command line:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /T /PID " + pid);
```

Firefox terminates "abnormally" and when I restart FF, I see message that FF crashed and I'm faced with option to either restore previous session or start new session. This does not happen when clicking the X icon in top right hand corner of FF browser.

Is there any way to close FF programmatically (in Java) without running into this issue?

Comment: How are you _launching_ Firefox? This is most typically done via Selenium, which has API calls to exit the browser.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I'm launching FF via CMD command: `String command = "cmd.exe /c start firefox -P " + profileName Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec(command);` I'm aware that Firefox is typically launched through Selenium. But for my purpose I need to launch it via CMD command. I cannot use Selenium for this. Hence my question how to close it so it terminates "normally" in this case.. Thanks.